# Ошибка в логах на сайте Heroku (discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.)

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py, ffmpeg

Сделал музыкального бота, закинул его на хостинг heroku, но он не может найти ffmpeg

Я понимаю что ffmpeg это экзешник, нельзя ли его как то загрузить на heroku чтобы бот работал?
Через консоль бот работает только при запуске от администратора

я новичек в этом, помогите пожалуйста

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При перед тем, как загружать данные и код, зайдите на странице вашего приложения во вкладку **Settings**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем промотайте до раздела **Buildpacks** и нажмите на кнопку **Add buildpack**.

Туда необходимо добавить две ссылки - FFMPEG и OPUS. Второй, вроде бы, тоже нужен для нормальной работы.

https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git

https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого, все должно заработать. Если, конечно, правильно написан код, и на Heroku установлены все необходимые модули.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Если данный ответ решил вашу проблему, могу я попросить вас отметить его как решение? :) Это даст другим пользователям понять, что данный вопрос закрыт и можно помогать другим людям

Comment: да решил, отмечайте

Comment: отметить должны вы, ваш же вопрос)

Comment: а я просто первый раз тут, сейчас